# Is It posible Apache or server Escape some Header like content_length?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, http-headers

In my case , I have a Laravel site , This script work prefect In Local ( My mean is show content_length Header ) , But When I run This Script in the Internet and My server , It Escape the content_length .

Screen shot (Local => It have a content_length ) :

[image]

But when i send this script in to the server It scape that .

My main purpose for getting content_length of file is that used content_length in my android downloader ( it need content_length for counting percent of downloaded file ) .

Thanks !

Comment: If the pages is a static file, or if a file is downloaded directly apache will add a content-length header because it knows how much data it is sending. But if the page is dynamically generated by a script or some other process, apache will not. The script must add it if it has some way to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve my problem With the Disable Gzip . All Of this problems happen for gzip .

I Disable that With :

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

In The .htaccess file . Thanks #<>